# Prove if a function is uniformly continuous on open interval, it is continuous on closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. Prove that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 5):

We need to show that $\lim_{x\to a; x\in (a,b)} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b; x\in (a,b)} f(x)$ exist.

Since $a$ is a limit point of $(a,b)$, we choose an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)\subset (a,b)$ such that $x_n \to a$. Plainly the sequence is Cauchy and  $(f(x_n))$ must also be  (because $f$ is uniformly continuous). Since $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy then, it  must  converges to some $L$. Since $(x_n)$ was arbitrary then   $\lim_{x\to a; x\in (a,b)} f(x) = L$. A similar argument works for $\lim_{x\to b; x\in (a,b)} f(x)$.

Define $F(x)= f(x)$ where $x\in (a,b)$,  $F(a)= \lim_{x\to a; x\in (a,b)} f(x) $ and $F(b)= \lim_{x\to b; x\in (a,b)} f(x)$. Now you only need to check that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ which is straightforward.

Comment: if one was a stickler for mathematical precision, they would specify the one-sided limits - I know... nit-picking.

Comment: @ChrisK: Or we can define $\lim_{x\to a: x\in (a,b)} f(x)=L$, =)

Comment: Indeed, we can do this as well.

Comment: It is not fully correct I believe. Why is it so, that $L$ is the same number for any $x_n$?